# C# Get CPU cache miss performance counter

Tags: c#, .net, cpu-cache

I know that CPUs count all L1/2/3 cache misses, and this info is accessible in principle. E.g. there is a performance viewer from Intel. I just cannot find an example in C#. Is this data accessible from .NET?

Comment: By perfomance viewer you mean Intel Performance Counter Monitor?

Comment: There are no built-in performance counters for it.  They are too hard to get to, only ring 0 code can read them.   And they heavily depend on the processor make and model.  Sure, a reason for being for Intel software.  Don't run it on an AMD processor :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can do this (on windows at least) using [Intel Perfomance Counter Monitor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor). In addition to other tools which come bundled with it, it contains PCM-Service - windows service which adds PCM windows perfomance counters. Once you downloaded, compiled and installed this service, you can access L2 cache misses (for example), as easy as this:

```
var pc = new PerformanceCounter("PCM Core Counters", "L2 Cache Misses", "total_"); // instead of total_ you can use number of core
var value = pc.RawValue; // or pc.NextValue() and so on.
```

Intel PCM adds much more interesting counters than just cache misses of course, all of which are accessible from .NET.

Comment: Is it possible to call a native lib via P/Invoke? I wan't no system dependencies such as Windows service, but am fine with a native xcopy-able dependency.

Comment: Library is written in C++ and provided with all sources. So I guess it should be possible to p-invoke there, though I personally didn't investigate details. At link above you can see a sample of how they suggest to use their library from code (C++ code), so you might try to create C++\CLI library to do the task.